# How can I make an image enlarge on a javascript event when its size is set through css?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, razor

I have some CSS ***(Below)*** defining an images size

```
#latestImages img 
{
    height: 95px;
    width: auto;
}
```

This is affecting these images:

```
<img src="@images.ImagePath" alt="@images.NameOfImage" />
```

When i set an onmouseover event to this image like so:

```
<img src="@images.ImagePath" alt="@images.NameOfImage" onmouseover="this.width=100;this.height=100;" onmouseout="this.width=200;this.height=200;"/>
```

The images height and width do change in the html when the source is viewed but there is no visible change, but when i removed the css the changes did occur.
Does anyone know why this is? And is there anything I can do different to keep the css as is and have javascript enlarging the image?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest way is to put all code in javascript.

Comment: Does this question need the `c#` and `razor` tags?

Comment: Nothing, test the answers, it has what I have said. (I'm spanish, this is the reason that I write bad english, sorry D=)

Comment: Just use JavaScript to change the CSS class to one that has different sizes set. You may need to use the !Important CSS hint as well. Here is a link to how you can change your CSS classes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the rapid responses ill give it another go with this new info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this format in your onmouseover handler: `this.style.width="50px"`.
Or better yet, don't put your JS in your HTML, and write a function for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
onmouseover="this.style.width='100px';this.style.height='100px';"
onmouseout="this.style.width='200px';this.style.height='200px';"
```

Styles need units. In this case `px`. Otherwise it could be `pt`, `in`, or `em`.